# responsive d3 area graph stretches circle interaction points

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have been experimenting with a simple **d3** google analytics-style area graph demo.  I'd like to make it stretch to the full width of its container, which I have managed to do.  However the little circles are of course stretching out of shape too. I'd like their positions to be responsive, but not their dimensions (so they remain circular).

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/46PfK/2/

I'm trying to use the [SVGPanUnscale.js](http://phrogz.net/svg/libraries/SVGPanUnscale.js) script. I have tried calling it with `unscaleEach('.dot');` and `[].forEach.call($('.dot'),unscale);` but neither appear to do anything.

This example is responsive in a similar way to mine and uses the script to 'unscale' the axis labels: http://meloncholy.com/static/demos/responsive-svg-graph-1/

This example also uses circle elements:
http://phrogz.net/svg/scale-independent-elements.svg

I looked at solutions involving the css attribute:

```
circle {
    vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

which created a circular stroke on an ellipse - weird.

A CSS solution would be preferable to a JS one, provided it works across browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, updated fiddle link

Comment: Not sure what you exactly need. Is something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/46PfK/3/ already enough, or do you need a real responsive solution (where you consider user can resize windows?). Anyway, I don't think there is a css solution, at least not as long as your circle are in the same svg element. You could create 2 groups in your svg, rescale only the group with your blue graph, and update the scale (only horizontal?) to display your circles at the right place).

Comment: @leMoisela My solution above should scale on window resize (at least in Chrome anyway).  I'm trying to use this graph in a web app, so it needs to scale horizontally as the user changes orientation. I think you're right though, some JS to redraw the graph on resize might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @leMoisela for pointing me in the right direction.  I fixed my issue nicely using JS to redraw the graph on resize:

http://jsfiddle.net/46PfK/4/

```
window.onresize = function(e){
    draw_graph();
};
```

Comment: seems like a bad idea to start the whole thing from scratch everytime

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example on resizing with D3 https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/

After you update your scales, only thing left to resize your circles would be something like this:

```
/* Force D3 to recalculate and update the points */
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .attr('cy', function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
    .attr('r', 4);
```